# multi label multi class classification problem

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to solve a aspect based sentiment analysis problem.

I am considering to devise a NN but am not sure if it is doable the way I am doing.
here is how I structure it.

I have a training set of 980 rows which contains 930 unique aspect values for 980 different sentences.

I am thinking of using lstm architecture by devising the problem as a multi label multi class problem.
so for input(a tokenized sentence) there will be 930 neurons at the output layer for each aspect and the nuerons will have 4 different classes(1 if the sentiment is positive 2 if negative 3 if neutral and 0 if the aspect doesnt exist for this sentence)

Do you think this is doable? I mean can a NN with 990 neurons for a fairly small data set(980 rows) be trained using colab's free gpus?

Comment: What you ask would be possible, but I am not sure it would be the best way to go. As is you only seems to have 1) a very small dataset and 2) a lot of aspect value (or more specifically a lot of unique different aspect). Maybe you can specify the problem (are you willing to identify a given name / topic ?) or share an exemple.